# Gnus C-c C-c opens a blank browser window

Tags: gnus

I am not able to send any mail from gnus. Upon hitting `C-c C-c` after writing the mail a blank window opens up in my webbrowser and nothing more happens (in the echo-buffer emacs says `Starting Firefox...`).
Also the mails showing in the INBOX group is not complete and up to date.

How should i get gnus to send and get mails?

Comment: It sounds like you have conflicting key bindings. When I compose an email, `C-c C-c` is bound to `message-send-and-exit`. Use `C-h k` to see what yours is bound to; that should help you track down the problem.

Comment: This is not a conflict. Doing `M-x message-send-and-exit` results again in a blank browser window

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Have you found any solution since then?